# Java driver equivalent for mongoshell's update multiple

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm trying to write Java code to remove multiple documents from an array field. I've been reading through MongoDB's documentation for how to use `$pull` in an update:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

And I keep seeing references to this syntax:

```
db.stores.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] }, vegetables: "carrots" } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

What exactly is the `{multi : true}` doing and is there any equivalent in the Java driver? I looked through `UpdateOptions` and didn't see anything that looked similar. I tried adding it to the `arrayFilters` list but I got an error from Mongo:

```
The array filter for identifier 'multi' was not used in the update
```

I understand the difference between the various update/updateOne/updateMany methods in the shell and their Java equivalents, but this syntax is new to me and the documentation uses it several times and I can't find any details on it.